# How to change TAB to SPACEs and set their amount in Brackets editor?

Tags: editor, text-editor, adobe-brackets

I'm using Brackets editor http://brackets.io/ and I'd like to change behavior when I click `TAB` key it will put 4 `SPACE`s instead and also I'd like to change amount of spaces added.

Is it possible to do this adjustment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the lower right corner of the editor, you'll see text saying `Spaces: 4` or the like.
You can click `Spaces` (or `Tab`) to toggle between those and click the number to change it.